# Use app data directory in NLog file path

Tags: logging, nlog

How can I set the `target` in the NLog.config file to create the log file in the user app data directory?

Below is the desired location of the file.

> C:\Users\userid\AppData\Local...\LogFile.txt

I tried setting the `fileName` in the following ways without any success.

- `target name="logfile" xsi:type="File" fileName="%APPDATA%/.../LogFile.txt"`
- `target name="logfile" xsi:type="File" fileName="${APPDATA}/.../LogFile.txt"`
- `target name="logfile" xsi:type="File" fileName="${%APPDATA%}/.../LogFile.txt"`

Answer (score 55, accepted):

You can achieve that by creating a target like this:

```xml
<target name="logfile" xsi:type="File"
    fileName="${specialfolder:folder=ApplicationData}/LogFile.txt"/>
```

The documentation can be found [here](https://github.com/nlog/NLog/wiki/Special-Folder-Layout-Renderer).

I hope this helps.

Comment: Hi @user2263865, can you mark the answer as accepted? It helps visitors with the same question and it helps me building reputation. ;-)

Answer (score 10):

The accepted answer doesn't create the log file in **AppData\Local** directory instead it creates the log file in **AppData\Roaming** directory.
As asked by the OP to **create the log file in AppData\Local** you have to use **LocalApplicationData** in specialfolder path.

```xml
<target name="logfile" xsi:type="File"
    fileName="${specialfolder:folder=LocalApplicationData}/ApplicationLogs/LogFile.txt"/>
```

Answer (score 4):

Just an addition to Jacco's answer, you can add a folder name to the path if you'd like the logs kept separately from other data that you might store in appdata, like this:

```xml
fileName="${specialfolder:folder=ApplicationData}/Logs/LogFile.txt"/>
```